# MYSQL query to Select the first duplicate record in JAVA

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to retrieve the the first row among the duplicate row, THE FIRST OCCURED ***

```
           --Table--

           Order_No    Product    User
              1         Book      Student
              2         Book      Student
              3         Book      Student
```

I want to get the Order_No of the first duplicate row in JAVA, I have used DISTINCT and DISTINCT TOP 1 etc but nothing worked, NEED HELP

Answer (score 0):

This is basic SQL?

```
SELECT min(order_no), product, user FROM table GROUP BY product, user
```

See also more information on [GROUP BY](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp)

Answer (score 0):

SELECT min(order_no), product, user 
FROM 'table'
GROUP BY user, product

Answer (score 0):

All fields not part of your group by must have some sort of way to determine which to pick of the n potentially different values. min() will pick the lowest value (even with strings and dates) while max() will pick the highest. You can also use First() and Last() to grab the value according to when they show up.

Supposing you had other values to pick from, you might see something like:

```
SELECT min(order_no), product, user, min(creation_date), 
    sum(quantity), first(billing_address) 
FROM orders GROUP BY product, user
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t.*
FROM table t
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT a
                   FROM table t2
                   WHERE t2.Product = t.Product
                   AND t2.User = t.User
                   AND t2.Order_No < t.Order_No
                  )
```